Merging multiple vars files in ansible playbook
I'm trying to see if I can split up a rather large var file in ansible.
This is the collection: https://github.com/Icinga/ansible-collection-icinga
---
- name: Build Icinga Image
  hosts: all
  become: yes
  vars_files:
    - vars/icinga-config/main.yml
  collections:
    - icinga.icinga

  tasks:     
    - ansible.builtin.include_role:
        name: icinga2        

The var file is structured like so:
icinga2_objects:
  internal.icinga:
    - name: host1.fqdn
       type: Host
       file: zones.d/main/host1.fqdn.conf
       address: 127.0.0.2
    - name: host2.fqdn
       type: Host
       file: zones.d/main/host2.fqdn.conf
       address: 127.0.0.3

Help please! I'm stuck as to what to try next
I have tried to put it into separate var file but one of the just gets ignored when I do this. This is an example:
- name: Build Icinga Image
  hosts: all
  become: yes
  vars_files:
    - vars/icinga-config/host1.yml
    - vars/icinga-config/host2.yml
  collections:
    - icinga.icinga

  tasks:     
    - ansible.builtin.include_role:
        name: icinga2        

The var files are structured like so:
vars/icinga-config/host1.yml
icinga2_objects:
  internal.icinga:
    - name: host1.fqdn
       type: Host
       file: zones.d/main/host1.fqdn.conf
       address: 127.0.0.2

vars/icinga-config/host2.yml
icinga2_objects:
  internal.icinga:
    - name: host2.fqdn
       type: Host
       file: zones.d/main/host2.fqdn.conf
       address: 127.0.0.3

Any ideas on how I can get them to merge without being ignored.

I have no experience with Icinga but its Monitoring Configuration Objects documentation clearly states that you should not use that icinga2_objects variable like you do:

The advantage of the default icinga2_objects variable is, that you can run your playbook over many different server without deploying the monitoring configuration on every host in the playbook. Otherwise the variable should be only placed in host_vars files to restrict deployment on every host.
As a secondary option, you can use the variable without the second level like the following example.

CAUTION! If not restricted it will be deployed on every host. This should be only defined in host_vars unless you know what you are doing!



Any ideas on how I can get them to merge without being ignored.

The caution note above comes from the way how Ansible variables are working in general.
Given that you didn't provide an example of your inventory, it looks to me that this question is a kind of X/Y problem - it seems that you need to figure out how to organize the variables first. It's hard to give a specific answer for your case because too many options are possible.
Which leaves to me no choice except from recommending to read the following pieces of  documentation very carefully:

Icinga collection documentation
How to build your inventory
Where should I put a variable
How the variables are merged


I'm only applying this on one host as it is being built via Packer.
